# R: Extract top nth values with ID/name

Tags: r, sorting, extract

I have a data frame with 21 variables and 1200 observations. The first column is the ID name for each species and column 21 is the total count of all the times each species was seen across multiple sites.

example columns: ID, RM1, RM2, RM10, Total

each row is an ID name and counts per river mile and total count

All I want is a list of the top 20 (or 100 for that matter) most abundant species and their total count. How do I do this?

This is driving me crazy and I don't want to do it in excel - there must be a way in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort you data frame, lets call it `df`, by Total, and take top 100

```
head(df[order(df$Total,decreasing = TRUE), ], 100)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Not sure why but when I use the script above I get: Error in `[.data.frame`(Rock18s, , order(Rock18s$Count, decreasing = TRUE)) : undefined columns selected. Any idea why?

Comment: usually it happens when you reference a non existent column. It'll be easier to see an error if you post a small reproducible example, exact code you are running...

Comment: So I brought in a csv file, the str function says it is a 'data.frame': 1297 obs. of  21 variables: and Count is a variable  that is an integer. The code I am using is: Top100<- head(Rock18s[,order(Rock18s$Count,decreasing = TRUE)], 100)

Comment: OK, my bad... comma was in a wrong place, should be this Top100<- head(Rock18s[order(Rock18s$Count,decreasing = TRUE),], 100), i corrected the answer above.

Comment: Awesome - it works now. I was so close on my own but it was driving me nuts. Thank you.